# Copy files from SFTP to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terminal, sftp

I am trying to copy file from an SFTP server to an S3 bucket and I get the following error:

```
cp: cannot create regular file `s3://bucket-name-anonymized/1001/': No such file or directory
```

This is the command I am using in the Terminal:

```
-bash-4.1$ cp my_proccesd_file.csv s3://bucket-name-anonymized/1001/
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se] or [su].

Answer (score 1):

The `cp` command is for local filesystems and does not know how to use Amazon S3.

Instead, use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

It has a `aws s3 cp` command, which knows how to communicate with Amazon S3. you will also need to configure credentials for access to S3.